# How can I manage my SQLite DB versions in Monotouch?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.ios

If I release my app, and in 2 weeks I release a new update, and I need to change the database, whats the solution?. For example in Android I´ve a SQlite library override Void that check the Database version. Thanks.

Comment: Why does your Android solution not work for iOS?

Comment: @Bosbon, the solution I mentioned isn´t mono for android, was plain android with Java, I guess the Sqlite library are different, for example the one I´m using in monotouch have a ORM implementation, the one in Android don´t. So that's why I was asking.

Comment: You question is really broad - can you be more specific about the problem you're facing?  There isn't any special general solution for db versioning in MonoTouch.

Comment: have a look at this. This may give u some idea.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13720206/sqlite-file-version-compatibility-within-an-application

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's lots of ways of doing this, but here's a system I've used in similar situations.

Keep the schema (and non-transactional data) as a baseline, and keep the version number in the database. Then, whenever you update your program, change the schema and save the change SQL in its own file. Name the files so that you number the files sequentially e.g. (`000001AddTableX.sql`, `000002RemoveColumnX.sql`, etc). Then write a chunk of code that checks a folder where all the changesets are saved. Then, if a changeset number in the filename is greater than the current version stored in the DB, run the changeset against the database.

This has the following benefits

- If you're using source control, your schema changesets will be saved and associated with the (presumably) related changes in the code when you check in your code.
- Your change set code will be well-tested because it'll be the *exact* code you used during development.
- No matter how many updates the end user has skipped, they'll get all the changesets in the right order when they finally do upgrade.

Comment: That is a really clever way of doing it.